# extended template working but main template is not working django

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
def base(request):

  return render(request,"base.html",{'':''})

def index(request):

 return render(request,"index.html",{'':''})
```

**base.html**

```
  <html>
    <head>ppppppppp</head>
    <body> 
   <h1>this is base template</h1>
 </body> 
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
 <body>
  <h1>
    Welcome to my app
   </h1>
 </body>`
{% endblock content %}
```

Here the issue is django is not at all recognising index.html only displaying extended template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct flow here is to create really :) **base** template:

**base.html**

```
<html>
    <head>ppppppppp</head>
    <body> 
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </body> 
</html>
```

And in your child templates you can override `{% block content %}` but leaving `<head>` etc common for all templates:

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
   <h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Also you should not write tag like `{% endblock BLOCKNAME %}`, just `{% endblock %}`

Comment: thank you for quick response, i am starter in django so i confused of this topic......now i got clear picture